# Using etherscan.io to get transaction method name from events

Tags: etherscan

I'm trying to retrieve the method name from the etherscan.io API. The method name appears in the etherscan.io reports, but I cannot for the life of me find any way to get it from the API.

[image]

Etherscan.io get txs docs: https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-normal-transactions-by-address